# Biology of Fantasy: Let's Get Real, Shall We?

Tags: discussion, reference

Before any of you asks, this has ***NO*** relation to the Anatomically Correct series.  That is someone else's series and put more emphasis on evolutionary plausibility than I am interested in.

If evolutionary plausibility were the goal for this series, we'd be here ***forever*** trying to find some justifications for the really extreme mythical creatures.

No, the ***real*** goal is to make it biologically feasible without resorting to the cliches and stereotypes that have been pounding them for centuries.

Comment: I certainly recall many DnD species having "made by a mad wizard!!!" as a creation source, so I support biologically feasible over evolutionarily plausible any day!

Answer (score 2):

### Those You Can Find on The Worldbuilding Stack Exchange

[Centaur](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55663/the-centaur-lets-get-real-shall-we)

[Angel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56222/the-angel-lets-get-real-shall-we)

[Dwarf](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56390/the-dwarf-lets-get-real-shall-we)

[Mer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/the-mer-lets-get-real-shall-we)

[Elf](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56815/the-elf-lets-get-real-shall-we)

[Reindeer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57021/the-reindeer-lets-get-real-shall-we)

### And This You Can Find on Medium

[Biology of Fantasy:  Let's Get Real, Shall We?](https://medium.com/universe-factory/biology-of-fantasy-lets-get-real-shall-we-ae5f13c2d464#.mpqvapows)